# using java htmlBuilder to build partial webpage

Tags: java, html, methods

I've been searching everywhere for a proper tutorial on using htmlBuilder for java. the only scraps of information I could find without combing through walls of text were building entire webpages with a single function.

say I want to build only part of a webpage

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Title!</h1>
        method that writes this middle part only.
    </body>
</html>
```

I still have yet to find much of anything useful as far as a usable example or tutorial. anything out there?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909801/better-html-builder-in-java

Comment: yeah. read that one. everybody want's to use their plugins. I feel I've added enough crap to my project, I saw 1 guy who was using pure java but we'll see if it works for me (cross your fingers!)

Comment: Java has a lot of built-in XML capabilities. Don't know enough about that so I won't write a full answer, but it should be worth a look.