# How to send data(table) from database via email in java?

Tags: java, html, sql, email, jakarta-mail

I can send regular emails (not from database), but how could I send full table in an email?
This is my code:

```
private static Message preparedMessage(Session session, String myAccountEmail,
        String recepient) {
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myAccountEmail));
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recepient));
        message.setSubject("Email using Java");
        String htmlTest="<h2> i'm sending an email!</h2>";
        message.setContent(htmlTest, "text/html"); 
       }
        return message;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaMailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried something simple like this:

```
     List <PetrolData> petrolList = MP_RacunDAO.select("03.08.2020", "11.08.2020"); //This is data that i want to put in table
       for(PetrolData pd : petrolList){
        String htmlTable = "<table border='1'> <tr> "
                + "<th>Column 1</td>"
                + "<th>Column 2</td>"
                + "<th>Column 3</td>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<td>"+pd.getTitle()+"</td>"
                + "<td>"+pd.getSum1()+"</td>"
                + "<td>"+pd.getSum2()+"</td>"                   
                + "</tr>"
                + "</table>";
            }
```

Obviously, It is not working for me, what can I do?

Comment: Why are you creating a table for each `PetrolData`? Wouldn't it be more suitable to add the create the table and the header once and add a single row for each `PetrolData`? If you don't want to use a library for html creation, use a `StringBuilder`, maybe...

Comment: @deHaar  I agree with you, that have more sense, but i'm not sure how to do that :D i can't just  put for each loop under first `<tr>`.

Comment: Can you show the `class PetrolData`?

Comment: @deHaar it's just a POJO class, i have four fields, constructor and getters for them. Do you still need  whole `class`?

Comment: Well then, not necessary... What type are the sums of? `int`? `double`? Anything else?

Comment: @deHaar  I have `String title` and `double sum1,sum2,sum3`.

Comment: Hmm... in your code, there are only 2 sums...

Comment: @deHaar Yeah i wrote just two for the simplicity, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an HMTL table in a row without using any external library, you can use a `StringBuilder` for that.

You would basically have to add the opening tag of the table and the header row **before** you loop through the data, then add a row for each `PetrolData` and after the loop you add the closing tag of the table.

See this example (which uses potentially unnecessary linebreaks and tabs, but they are useful for example output, because I won't send an email here):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // sample data
    List<PetrolData> petrolDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    petrolDataList.add(new PetrolData("Petrol 1", 4.1f, 8.2f, 12.4f));
    petrolDataList.add(new PetrolData("Petrol 2", 5.3f, 9.2f, 13.24f));
    petrolDataList.add(new PetrolData("Petrol 3", 6.0f, 10.1f, 14.312f));
    petrolDataList.add(new PetrolData("Petrol 4", 7.7f, 11.9f, 15.15f));
    petrolDataList.add(new PetrolData("Petrol 5", 8.45f, 12.0f, 16.936f));
    petrolDataList.add(new PetrolData("Petrol 6", 9.67f, 13.2f, 17.777f));
    
    StringBuilder htmlTableBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    // open the table
    htmlTableBuilder.append("<table border=\"1\">").append(System.lineSeparator());
    // open a rown, header row here
    htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("<tr>").append(System.lineSeparator());
    // add the headers to the header row
    htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<th>").append("Title").append("</th>").append(System.lineSeparator());
    htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<th>").append("Sum 1").append("</th>").append(System.lineSeparator());
    htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<th>").append("Sum 2").append("</th>").append(System.lineSeparator());
    htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<th>").append("Sum 3").append("</th>").append(System.lineSeparator());
    // close the header row
    htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("</tr>").append(System.lineSeparator());
    
    // add a data row for each PetrolData
    for (PetrolData pd : petrolDataList) {
        // open a row again
        htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("<tr>").append(System.lineSeparator());
        // add the data
        htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<td>").append(pd.getTitle()).append("</td>").append(System.lineSeparator());
        htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<td>").append(pd.getSum1()).append("</td>").append(System.lineSeparator());
        htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<td>").append(pd.getSum2()).append("</td>").append(System.lineSeparator());
        htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("\t").append("<td>").append(pd.getSum3()).append("</td>").append(System.lineSeparator());
        // close the row
        htmlTableBuilder.append("\t").append("</tr>").append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    // and close the table
    htmlTableBuilder.append("</table>");
    
    // then print the result
    System.out.println(htmlTableBuilder.toString());
}
```

The output of this is the following, which you could easily embed in a valid HTML mail:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Sum 1</th>
        <th>Sum 2</th>
        <th>Sum 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrol 1</td>
        <td>4.099999904632568</td>
        <td>8.199999809265137</td>
        <td>12.399999618530273</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrol 2</td>
        <td>5.300000190734863</td>
        <td>9.199999809265137</td>
        <td>13.239999771118164</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrol 3</td>
        <td>6.0</td>
        <td>10.100000381469727</td>
        <td>14.312000274658203</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrol 4</td>
        <td>7.699999809265137</td>
        <td>11.899999618530273</td>
        <td>15.149999618530273</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrol 5</td>
        <td>8.449999809265137</td>
        <td>12.0</td>
        <td>16.93600082397461</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Petrol 6</td>
        <td>9.670000076293945</td>
        <td>13.199999809265137</td>
        <td>17.777000427246094</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Pay attention** to the format of `double`s, you might have to apply a `DecimalFormat` or anything similar for correct values to be shown.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. But there is a lot of code for a simple table. What did you have in mind for external library? Is this how programmers send table in general?

Comment: Yes, it's a lot of code because HTML needs a lot of code. No, programmers would usually use a library that makes life easier (like suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909801/better-html-builder-in-java/9909951)) or have template files with the basic structure of the email or page which they load/read and then just build up a table and insert it there.

Comment: Thank you again, you have been very helpful